# Not understanding the output of stdout.write(str(x)) when x is an int

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python. I am trying to understand how stdout.write() works.
I not understanding the output when I print x after I assign it to 6.

[image]

I am not understanding why there is an extra 1 in the output.
I thought the ascii value of return key is 1. So, I executed the following method:

I got the following output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.write: `.write` *"return[s] the number of bytes written"*. What you're seeing is the value `6` being written, followed by the interactive shell giving you the number of bytes that were written (`1`).

Comment: Can you please suggest a way to print only the value and not the number of bytes returned?

Comment: Since you probably won't execute "real" code in the interactive shell, this is mostly a non-issue. If you save this code in a .py file and execute it, you will not see the implicit return value of the last statement. That is a feature of the interactive shell to help you test small snippets quickly and see their result.

Answer (score 2):

this is because `stdout.write` writes your `6` to the screen, then **returns** `1` (the number of characters printed to the screen) and the shell prints this as well, just like it would print the return value of any other function

just use: `print(x)`

Comment: Yeah, I can use print. But stdout.write() is faster than print. I am curious if there is a way to do it using stdout.write().

Comment: well, in a real script it will not print the return value. this is just because you're running in an interactive shell. try writing your example in a .py file and running it, you should only see 6